# Auth0 callback url with Angular2 Not working

Tags: angular, auth0

I have setup Angular2 ,Auth0 facebook login which I can login,get access token and everything is working.but when I'm login, allowed callback URL is not working.It store the data in localstorage and keep loading to same page.I have included allowed callback url under auth0 client and add as options as well.anyone solved this issue?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';


declare const Auth0Lock: any;

const  options = {
      auth: {
        redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/profile'
      }
    };

    @Injectable()


    export class Auth0Service {

      lock = new Auth0Lock('<key>', '<url>', options );

      constructor() {


        this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
          this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function (error: any, profile: any) {
            if (error){
              throw new Error(error);
            }

            localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));

          });
        });


      }
```